# Java says I'm not overriding but my override is being told it has nothing to override

Tags: java, gson

My code is as follows:

```
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
public class JsonElmExt extends JsonElement
{
        @Override
        public JsonElmExt deepCopy()
        {
                return null;
        }
}
```

But I get the following errors:

```
JsonElmExt is not abstract and does not override abstract method deepCopy() in JsonElement
method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
```

I'm confused because my code is similar to how the library itself overrides deepCopy() here: https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/JsonObject.java
What am I missing?

Comment: The return type is probably wrong

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos Return type is not part of the method signature, so is not considered for override matching.

Comment: @Andreas ReturnType must be covariant of the super implementation. JsonElement is not a instance of a JsonObject.

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos True, `JsonObject` is a subclass of `JsonElement`, but I don't know what your point is, since `deepCopy()` returns a `JsonElement` and `JsonElmExt` *is* a subclass of `JsonElement`. Nothing involved here is about `JsonObject`.

Comment: @Andreas just comment around he saying that the method returns JsonObject in the signature

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos OP was linking to that as an *example* of other code doing a similar thing to what OP is trying to do, i.e. a subclass of `JsonElement` that implements `deepCopy()`, but changing the return type to another type that *is* a subclass of the return type declared in the base class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note: GSON 2.8.2 changed method to `public`, so upgrading will fix the issue.*

The error message I see in Eclipse to more informative:

> This class must implement the inherited abstract method `JsonElement.deepCopy()`, but cannot override it since **it is not visible from `JsonElmExt`**. Either make the type abstract or make the inherited method visible

The problem is that the *abstract* method `deepCopy()` is **package-private**, effective preventing subclassing from outside the `com.google.gson` package.

[`JsonElement`](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/JsonElement.html) is an abstract class representing the [JSON](https://www.json.org/) element types: [Objects](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/JsonObject.html), [arrays](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/JsonArray.html), and literals ([`null`](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/JsonNull.html) and the [primitives](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/JsonPrimitive.html): string, number, `true`, and `false`).

JSON doesn't have any more types, so why are you trying to create a fifth type of JSON element? Re-think what you're doing.

If you need help with that, create a new question, describing what you're *trying* to do, because your current question is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/351454), i.e. you're going in the wrong direction for whatever it is you *really* need to do.

Comment: [`deepCopy` is not package-private](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/gson-parent-2.8.2/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/JsonElement.java#L39) since [May 31, 2017](https://github.com/google/gson/commit/3090a7ed2af4d6d2e6bd3647d12839bb4ad404e8).

Comment: @TeWu I was using 2.8.1, and that change is in 2.8.2. Getting 2.8.2 fixed the compile error, so it appears that OP is also running an older version.

Comment: I'm creating a new JsonElement type so that I can add extra methods that combine .get() and things like JsonObject's .getAsString() but that deal with nulls for me.